# Excel Not Responding During Macro

Tags: performance, excel, vba

I have a macro that runs on a continous loop 24/7.  The computer will occasionally freeze but there is no error in the excel code.  The code uses the following in order to run efficiently:

```
DoEvents
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
startagain:
'code
'calculations, alerts, and screen are updated
GoTo startagain
```

I also am using what I believe is an efficient method of copying and pasting (a bulk of the code is pasting values and formulas):

```
Length = Range("C1").Value
Set rng = Sheets("Linked Data").Range("A2:AA" & Length)
Range("A2").Value = rng.Value
```

I have chagned the processor priority on the computer to "high" for EXCEL.exe, I have the computer performance set to maximum performance, I have disable all un-necessary add-ins, and I have turned off autorecover saving.

Despite all of the above, the computer will sometimes freeze and become unresponsive.  Does anyone know anything that can be done to improve the reliability?

Comment: Are any other applications running on the machine? Any user interaction? You may want to set your rng variable to nothing at the end of every loop.

Comment: Do you have a DoEvents clause inside of your loop? Try putting it just below the startagain:

Comment: No other applications running.  I add clearing the variables after they are used.  What beneift would be seen by moving the doevents within the loop?

Comment: The DoEvents allows windows to process queue activities and keyboard inputs. It could prevent your screen freeze...

Comment: I know what the doevents does, but does it require me to add a "doevents" line at the start of every loop?  I run ~5 loops within the macro

Comment: If the loop is long-running, DoEvents allows for a brief pause on each cycle for the OS to catch up other activities

Comment: gotcha....so doevents is not like a continual statment...it creates a pause to catch up at every doevents you have in the code?  Is this correct?

Comment: Thats correct. Each time you call the DoEvents method it pauses to catch up.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid Goto and use **Application.OnTime Method** to run a procedure repeatively.

You can also think of creating a Automation-addin which may lead to performance imporvement as its compiled code.

Kindly refer this [link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AutomationAddIns.aspx)

You may also refer this link for performance imporvement [link](http://www.excelitems.com/2010/12/optimize-vba-code-for-faster-macros.html)

Comment: Can you further define what you mean by: "You can also think of creating a Automation-addin which may lead to performance imporvement as its compiled code."

Comment: Is there a benefit to using the Application.OnTime Method?  The gotostart again allows the macro to refresh the data as soon as the macro completes.

Comment: Automation addin are similar to xla addin like (solver addin or analysis toolpack)  but they are compiled code and hence run faster. You may refer to the link provided for complete details. Also request you put your entire code when its something for performance improvement so that you get better solution.

Comment: Thank you - the performance link is very helpful.  The code is 350 lines ...I will add some of the performance enhancements you discussed then repost in a few days.